# Hard aggregation query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle SQL, and i need some help with a query. I have no idea how to do that.

I have the following table (`table_a`):

```
Mortgage_ID (int)
Doc_ID (int)
Status (varchar)
```

Each document can be sent many times for the same mortgage.

From the table above i've made the following table (`table_b`):

```
Rank (int)
Document_type (int)
Count (int)
```

This table is containing the global count of the top 40 popular documents from `table_a` (regardless the status). For example:

```
Rank |   Doc_ID   | count
--------------------------
1    |   212121   | 90
2    |   555111   | 82
3    |   4567654  | 76
.    |    .       | .
.    |    .       | .
.    |    .       | .
40   |   54321    | 22
```

Now i need to create the following table: For each mortgage from `table_a`, I need the count of the documents that has been sent for each one of the top 40 documents with the status "OK".

For example:

```
Mortgage_id |  Pop1 | Pop2 | Pop3 | ... | Pop40
-------------------------------------------------
    123     |  50   | 21   |  30  | ... | 6
    555     |  70   | 0    |  21  | ... | 40
    654     |  100  | 96   |  58  | ... | 0
```

Pop1 doc (the most popular document) has been sent 50 times with the status "OK" for Mortgage_ID 123. Pop2 has been sent 21 times with status "OK" for Mortgage_id 123 and so on.

I hope the description is clear enough. Is anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: This is called a PIVOT.  Depending on your version of Oracle, you can use the PIVOT function or you could use an aggregate function with CASE expression to convert rows into columns.

Comment: for future questions read [this](http://tkyte.blogspot.de/2005/06/how-to-ask-questions.html), please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, this is a `join` to combine the two tables and then a `pivot`.  In this case, I would use conditional aggregation.  So, I think this is what you are looking for:

```
select a.mortgage_id,
       sum(case when b.rank = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as pop1,
       sum(case when b.rank = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as pop2,
       . . .
       sum(case when b.rank = 40 then 1 else 0 end) as pop40
from table_b b join
     table_a a
     on b.doc_id = a.doc_id
group by a.mortgage_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select *
  from (select ta.Mortgage_ID, rank, cnt
          from table_a ta, table_b tb
         where ta.doc_id = tb.doc_id
       )
pivot (
  sum(cnt)
  for rank in (1 pop1,2 pop2,3 pop3,4 pop4,5 pop5)
)

MORTGAGE_ID       POP1       POP2       POP3       POP4       POP5
----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
          1                               20
          2         40
          5                                          10
          4                                                      5
          3                    30
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/35824)